# feeding special characters using awk system into python sys.argv

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have this python script:

`cat tst.py`

```
import sys

x = sys.argv[1]

print(x)
print(type(x))
```

I have the following file

`cat input.txt`

```
ID    location    value
ID1   location1   NM_002099.7:c.59C>T
ID2   location2   NM_002099.7:c.71G>A
```

I am trying to run:

`awk 'NR>1' | while read -r ID location value; do python3.8 tst.py "$value"; done`

Is there a way to do this using awk? ie:

```
awk 'NR>1 {system("python3 tst.py $3")}'
```

Comment: Use double quotes.

Comment: I see! I'm surprised I missed it. Initially tried awk. Changed the question to see if there is a way to use awk system. The awk command I pipe from is much more complicated

Comment: I would actually advise against putting awk code inside of single quotes because many characters special to awk are also special for the shell. Instead, use `-v` to inject a variable.

Comment: I meant to say "double" not "single" in the previous comment.

Comment: `awk -v val=$3 "{system("python tst.py $3")}" file.txt` ? I assume I misunderstood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the argument for `system`.

You could do it in double quotes:

```
awk 'NR>1 {system("python3 tst.py \"" $3 "\"")}'
```

But double quotes will make `$(echo something)` work as in shell. It's better to quote it in single quotes. Because you can't do `'` inside `awk` script, it's popular to use a variable set to single quote or use `\x27` it's ascii value inside `awk` script:

```
awk -vq="'" 'NR>1 {system("python3 tst.py " q $3 q)}'
```

It will fail of course, if the argument `$3` itself has single quotes in it. What you could do is write your own quoting function. Just substitute single quotes `'` for `'\''` sequence and use single quotes to quote it, so for example `abc'def` in input becomes `'abc'\''def'` when passed to shell:

```
awk -vq="'" 'NR>1 {gsub(q, q "\\" q q, $3); system("echo tst.py " q $3 q)}'
```

In awk everything inside `"` is taken as a string. So `awk 'NR>1 {system("python3 tst.py $3")}'` will try to run literally `python3 tst.py $3`. As `$3` expands to the 3rd argument in the shell, it will expand to nothing and this will just run `python3 tst.py`. You want to concatenate the string `python3 tst.py` with the result of `$3` in `awk`, thus `system("python3 tst.py " $3)`.

Comment: I tried `"python3 tst.py q $3 q"` before posting. q has to be outside the `"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to only use `awk` for the text processing and pipe it's output to `xargs` before calling the python script:

**input**

```
ID    location    value
ID1   location1   NM_002099.7:c.59C>T
ID2   location2   NM_002099.7:c.71G>A
```

**Command**

```
awk 'NR>1{print $3}' input.txt | xargs -L 1 python tst.py
```

**Output**

```
NM_002099.7:c.59C>T
<type 'str'>
NM_002099.7:c.71G>A
<type 'str'>
```

**Notes**

As long as there is no space in the `values` it should work, also note that if there are spaces in the `values` they will not be extracted properly by `awk` in the first place.